# Get rid of words that have fewer than 3 or more than 6 characters

Tags: r, list

I have here a small list of strings:

```
> dput(test)
list(c("jason", "s", "jasonnnnnnnnn"))
```

I would like to get rid of certain short (less than 3 characters) and 
long (more than 6 characters) words. I've tried this code to no avail.

```
test[[ii]] <- 
      lapply(test[[ii]], function(x) x[-(nchar(x < 5 | x > 10))])
```

Comment: `lapply(test, function(x) x[!(nchar(x) < 3 | nchar(x) > 6)])`

Comment: Or using `nchar(x[[1]]) >= 3 & nchar(x[[1]]) < 6`

Comment: @akrun Your code doesn't work

Comment: I made a typo earlier, it should work now

Comment: The essential problem with your code is that `(nchar(x < 5 | x > 10))` is `logical`, that is, a vector of TRUE or FALSE values. To get rid of the TRUEs and keep the FALSEs, you need to either negate with `!` (not `-`), or you can turn those into indexes with `which()` and those indexes you can negate with `-`. So `-which(nchar(x < 5 | x > 10))` would also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x <- list(c("jason", "s", "jasonnnnnnnnn"))
lapply(x, function(x) x[nchar(x) %in% 3:6])
[[1]]
[1] "jason"
```

What matters is as Gregor has pointed out the difference between subsetting with integers (where you can use `-`) and logicals.

Answer (score 2):

If we are using the `|` operator, negate (`!`) and subset the words that fall within 3:6

```
lapply(test, function(x) x[!(nchar(x) < 3 | nchar(x) > 6)])
#[[1]]
#[1] "jason"
```

Comment: Wierd that I didn't see any answer when I posted mine but says yours is 2min older.

Comment: @snoram I posted it earlier, then I deleted it to make sure that I read it correctly :=)